# Access Query not returning Date

Tags: ms-access-2013

Below is a query I ran just to try and investigate why one of my more complex queries isnt returning dates that I know are in tables. The query is in fact returning nothing.

Any idea why?

```
 SELECT [Table].[Date Completed]
 FROM [Table] WHERE [Table].[Date Completed]=6/28/2016;
```

Comment: beat me to it, post as answer and recieve feedback :) @DarrenBartrup-Cook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of ways you can do this - it all boils down to getting SQL to recognise the date in the correct format.

So, as you've found yourself you can use:

```
SELECT [Date Completed] FROM Table WHERE [Date Completed] = #6/28/2016#
```

you could also use:

```
SELECT [Date Completed] FROM Table1 WHERE [Date Completed] = CDATE("28-Jun-2016")
```

This would also work:

```
SELECT [Date Completed] FROM Table1 WHERE [Date Completed] = #2016/06/28#
```

and this:

```
SELECT [Date Completed] FROM Table1 WHERE [Date Completed] = 42549
```

It's just a case of getting SQL to recognise the date.

Comment: This is super cool. This will certainly prove to be an awesome resource for future troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

Exact dates should between `#`

```
SELECT [Table].[Date Completed]
FROM [Table] 
WHERE [Table].[Date Completed]=#6/28/2016#;
```